# When can we say that two representations of an island's shore line are topologically equivalent? Is Luzon an instructive case?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Under [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/239311/51174) to "Is this 'satellite photo' the only representation of the shape of Gilligan's Island?" is a short discussion of the degree of similarity between drawings of a famous but fictitious island.

> "...I fail to see any noteworthy similarity between those two, the third one, or the one from the question, beyond being islands with a non-convex outline.

> t helps if you turn the pictures upside and squint a little

> "topologically equivalent"

**Question:** When can we say that two representations of an island's shore line are topologically equivalent? Are these three topologically equivalent? Do lagoons, inlets and the possibility of inland lakes along with the external shore line all play a role in this determination?

For example, can we say that all islands without land-locked lakes are topologically equivalent? Does [An Island Within a Lake, On an Island Within a Lake on an Island](https://seasia.co/2019/02/03/an-island-within-a-lake-on-an-island-within-a-lake-on-an-island) (the case of [Luzon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzon) in the Philippines) provide an instructive example?

---

Images from the linked question for background context only:

[image: Map of the island from Forward March.] [image: Map of the island from Forward March.] [image: Map of the island from Forward March.]

The image in the original question:

[image: Gilligan's island "seen from space"]

Comment: There's a silent close vote for "This question doesn’t meet a Mathematics Stack Exchange guideline." Would it be possible to say *which* guideline that is so that I could address the issue right away? *Thanks!*

Comment: I've added the geometry tag added for its similarities and transformations aspects, but I'm not sure if it applies here or not.

Comment: I'm assuming there's an algorithm for *similarity* but you'd need to feed it more examples.

Comment: @Richard in that case I'll just remove the tag to keep the focus on topological equivalence.